# Is it strange to use "dilemma" when not referring to two difficult choices?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Definition:

> **dilemma**
>
> a situation in which a difficult choice has to be made between two or
>   more alternatives, especially ones that are equally undesirable.
>
> a difficult situation or problem.

Source: [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=dilemma%20define&biw=1280&bih=938&ei=Li99VfzSIYPPmwXVupewBQ&start=0&sa=N).

Example sentence:

> The dilemma of modern life: trying to find an outlet outside of your
>   house.

I guess this sentence fits the second definition. So is it correct? (Or should I use another word instead?)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - good finding,  actually I am giving a different answer. The question is not really about two or more options, but it refers to  the usage of *dilemma* as a generic term meaning *problem*.

Comment: The answer depends on whether you want to be the sand-castle or the ocean wave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dilemma](http://2.%20Usage%20Problem%20A%20problem%20that%20seems%20to%20defy%20a%20satisfactory%20solution.) is also used as a generic term meaning *problem*:

> - (Usage Problem)  A problem that seems to defy a satisfactory solution. (AHD)

You can use it with that meaning in your sentence.